# Calling an async method from a constructor in Dart

Tags: asynchronous, constructor, dart

Let's assume that an initialization of MyComponent in Dart requires sending an HttpRequest to the server. Is it possible to construct an object synchronously and defer a 'real' initialization till the response come back?

In the example below, the _init() function is not called until "done" is printed. Is it possible to fix this?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

class MyComponent{
  MyComponent() {
    _init();
  }

  Future _init() async {
    print("init");
  }
}

void main() {
  var c = new MyComponent();
  sleep(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  print("done");
}
```

**Output**:

```
done
init
```

Comment: Can you use a static async method?

Comment: how should it wait for something without the use of 'await' anyway?

Answer (score 161):

Probably the best way to handle this is with a factory function, which calls a private constructor.

In Dart, private methods start with an underscore, and "additional" constructors require a name in the form `ClassName.constructorName`, since Dart doesn't support function overloading. This means that private constructors require a name, which starts with an underscore (`MyComponent._create` in the below example).

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

class MyComponent{
  /// Private constructor
  MyComponent._create() {
    print("_create() (private constructor)");

    // Do most of your initialization here, that's what a constructor is for
    //...
  }

  /// Public factory
  static Future<MyComponent> create() async {
    print("create() (public factory)");

    // Call the private constructor
    var component = MyComponent._create();

    // Do initialization that requires async
    //await component._complexAsyncInit();

    // Return the fully initialized object
    return component;
  }
}

void main() async {
  var c = await MyComponent.create();

  print("done");
}
```

This way, it's impossible to accidentally create an improperly initialized object out of the class. The only available constructor is private, so the only way to create an object is with the factory, which performs proper initialization.

Comment: This also hides the details of object creation from the sender

Comment: I think this is a better solution. The only drawback is that if you enable null safety and if you have some variables that are initialised asynchronously, you have to declare them as nullable. This is a little bit annoying. Any idea to avoid that?

Comment: You can use the `late` keyword with your properties @Marco

Comment: This is a better answer because it simplifies the creation of the object. There's no need to be scared off by the factory pattern.

Comment: I think this is the best approach.  I hope that the `factory` keyword in Dart will be extended to support async object creation & initialization which will make this pattern a little cleaner syntactically.

Comment: MyComponent._() this naming works as well.

Answer (score 117):

A constructor can only return an instance of the class it is a constructor of (`MyComponent`). Your requirement would require a constructor to return `Future<MyComponent>` which is not supported.

You either need to make an explicit initialization method that needs to be called by the user of your class like:

```
class MyComponent{
  MyComponent();

  Future init() async {
    print("init");
  }
}

void main() async {
  var c = new MyComponent();
  await c.init();
  print("done");
}
```

or you start initialization in the consturctor and allow the user of the component to wait for initialization to be done.

```
class MyComponent{
  Future _doneFuture;

  MyComponent() {
    _doneFuture = _init();
  }

  Future _init() async {
    print("init");
  }

  Future get initializationDone => _doneFuture
}

void main() async {
  var c = new MyComponent();
  await c.initializationDone;
  print("done");
}
```

When `_doneFuture` was already completed `await c.initializationDone` returns immediately otherwise it waits for the future to complete first.

Comment: I see the former pattern a lot, but I don't think it is a good one.  It breaks the RAII design principle (Resource Acquisition is Initialization).  When you obtain an object, it is best if it is fully initialized and ready to use.  The second pattern is no better as you are inviting bugs where you forget to wait for `initializationDone`

Comment: @jlyonsmith if there are no alternatives you use what you get. What you want is, to my knowledge, currently not possible in Dart. There are also no destructors, so you can't release the resource when the instance is released. So it's at least consistent ;-)

Comment: I'm doing similar now unfortunately(Glad this confirms what i did is not as ridiculous as i felt it was) .  Been coding for 30+ yrs and seeing bombardment of solutions/enhancements/frameworks introduced to languages in order to address a 10% problem but end up butchering the other 90%.  I'm not just talking Dart either.   There is nothing accomplished today with coding that wasn't possible in the 90's and early 2000's with less memory/hardware/resources.... but the amount of complexity to accomplish the same things today is 3x more minimum in most modern lang/frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, an asynchronous factory function would help Dart devs with this problem.  @kankaristo has IMHO given the best answer, a static async method that returns a fully constructed and initialized object. You have to deal with the async somehow, and breaking the init in two will lead to bugs.