# Waiting for result of Future<DocumentSnapshot> in Flutter Firestore

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a cloud FireStore database with 2 fields.

- imageUrl (url of a remote file)
- user (reference field of a document in users collection)

Below is how I get the documents from the images collection.

```
    class ImagePost {

      final String imageUrl;

      final User user;

      const ImagePost(
          {this.imageUrl,
          this.user});

      factory ImagePost.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot document) {
        User userInfo;

        DocumentReference userReference = document['user'];
        Future<DocumentSnapshot> userRef = userReference.get();

       userRef.then((document) {
          userInfo = User.fromJSON(document.data);
        });

        ImagePost post = new ImagePost(
          imageUrl: document['imageUrl'],
          user: userInfo // ==> always null while returning
        );

        return post;
      }
    }
```

When getting the reference user document, the `post` object always contains null value for user field. I expect the user object to be populated.

But the user value is retrieved late and not returned along with the post object.

How can I ensure that user value is retrieve before returning the post value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an async method from component constructor in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933801/calling-an-async-method-from-component-constructor-in-dart)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the `get()` method return a Future and you need to use `async` 'await' in order to wait for the response , but is not posible to use it in your `constructor`.

Just create a method (not constructor) and use like this :

```
  Future<ImagePost> getImagePostFromDocument(DocumentSnapshot document) async {
    DocumentReference userReference = document['user'];
    DocumentSnapshot userRef = await userReference.get();
    User userInfo = User.fromJSON(userRef);
    ImagePost post = new ImagePost(
        imageUrl: document['imageUrl'],
        user: userInfo 
        );
    return post;
  }
```

I recommend you to call it form a [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: It helps. Is there a better way to avoid second remote call for getting user details for every item?

Comment: You can put that in another so question posting the code that you have. For now it my answer help you , mark it as solved to avoid misunderstanding. Thanks