# Unhandled Exception: Content size below specified contentLength. 206 bytes written but expected 375482. #228

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to upload multiple files with [multi_image_picker](https://github.com/Sh1d0w/multi_image_picker) with the code below but I'm receiving the error in the title. I'm following the code in the [document](https://sh1d0w.github.io/multi_image_picker/#/upload?id=server-api) but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way.
Thanks in advance

```
Future<void> sendDataToServer() async {
    // string to uri
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Settings.SERVER_URL + 'api/uploadproduct');

// create multipart request
    MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    request.fields['name'] = productName;

    List.generate(images.length, (index) async {
      Asset asset = images[index];

      ByteData byteData = await asset.getByteData();
      List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

      MultipartFile multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'photos',
        imageData,
        filename: 'some-file-name.jpg',
        contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg"),
      );

      // add file to multipart
      request.files.add(multipartFile);
    });

// send
    var response = await request.send();
  }
```

**UPDATE AND SOULUTION**

Thanks to @Richard Heap answer I could find a solution I'm adding the solution here because his answer is not the complete solution:

```
Future<void> sendDataToServer() async {
    // string to uri
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Settings.SERVER_URL + 'api/uploadproduct');

// create multipart request
    MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    request.fields['name'] = productName;

    for (var asset in images) { {
      Asset asset = images[index];

      ByteData byteData = await asset.getByteData();
      List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

      MultipartFile multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'photos[]', //this [] little change was needed to make it work
        imageData,
        filename: 'some-file-name.jpg',
        contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg"),
      );

      // add file to multipart
      request.files.add(multipartFile);
    };

// send
    var response = await request.send();
  }
```

Comment: May be related [Calling an async method from component constructor in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933801/calling-an-async-method-from-component-constructor-in-dart)

Answer (score 1):

Change `List.generate` to:

```
  var i = 0;
  for (var asset in images) {
    i++;
    var multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      'photo$i',
      (await asset.getByteData()).buffer.asUint8List(),
      filename: 'photo$i.jpg', // use the real name if available, or omit
      contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg'),
    );

    request.files.add(multipartFile);
  }
```

This will result in numbered params `photo1`, `photo2`, etc.

Your trick of appending the `[]` might only work with a PHP-based server that understands that suffix to mean an array of parameters called `photos`. The individually numbered approach is more generic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's sending wrong data's when I'm catching it on the server side.

Comment: That's the data that I'm catching on the server "/tmp/php72NKQa"

Comment: Presumably that's the temp file that the server has put your image in, right?

Comment: Maybe right, but when I'm uploading the same data from a web form it's uploaded successfully. that's why I think it's the wrong data from Flutter.

Comment: Experiment with just a plain Dart command line app, using some dummy image data. Also, note that you should be using different values for the first and third parameters of `MultipartFile.fromBytes` if you are selecting more than one image.

Comment: You mean different names for filename: parameter? if you mean that I added different names and it's not working with one image too.

Comment: yes and the field parameter. Just a reminder for when you want to do more that one image.

Comment: Thanks to your reminder I could find it out. with one small change in the first parameter from changing "photos" to "photos[]" it did work. they should mention that in the document.

Comment: Please update your answer to check it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue

```
 Files.forEach((val) async{
  var MyFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('MediaFiles[]',val);
  Multi.files.add(
    MyFile,
  );
});
```

i change just "forEach" to "for" loop and its work for me.

Working code

```
for(var val in Files){
  var MyFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('MediaFiles[]',val);
  Multi.files.add(
    MyFile,
  );
}
```