# Waiting until constructor / init function will initialize members of the class

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

Currently, when I'm running `await myService.getItem()` I'm getting a null pointer exception because `_box` isn't initialized yet. How to be sure, that my `_initialize` function is finished before calling any other function from `MyService`?

```
class MyService {

  Box<Item> _box;

  MyService() {
    _initialize();
  }

  void _initialize() async {
    _box = await Hive.openBox<Storyboard>(boxName);
  }

  Future<Item> getItem() async {
    return _box.get();
  }
}
```

For creating `MyService` I'm using Provider like:

```
final myService = Provider.of<MyService>(context, listen: false);
```

Comment: I believe this question has been asked before - [Possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38966743/4241571)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. What you can do it make sure your method depending on initialization waits until it's really done before continuing:

```
class MyService {
  Box<Item> _box;
  Future<void> _boxInitialization;

  MyService() {
    _boxInitialization = _initialize();
  }

  Future<void> _initialize() async {
    _box = await Hive.openBox<Storyboard>(boxName);
  }

  Future<Item> getItem() async {
    await _boxInitialization; // this might still be ongoing, or maybe it's already done
    return _box.get();
  }
}
```

I'm not really happy with that solution, it's feel a little... off, but it would do the trick.